convert list to datatable recursive c#
I am trying to convert a list to data table but recurrsively.
for example: I have list of users where every user may or may not contain company info. Company can contains another complex object. This hierarchy can go even deeper to 10-15 levels.
I am trying to create a generic function which can convert list to data table.
the nexted object will be displayed as below in column name...
user.username
user.company.Companyname
user.company.CompanyType

I also wants to control the depth of recurrsive columns.
here is what I have created...
protected DataTable ToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> users)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();   

    GenerateTableColumns(dt, typeof(T), new Stack<string>(), new List<string>(), 2);
    var list = users.ToList();
    foreach (T item in list)
    {
        GenerateTableRows<T>(dt, item, (i, columnName) => GetColumnValue(i, new Stack<string>(columnName.Split('.').Reverse())));
    }
    return dt;
}

private static Type BaseType(Type oType)
{
    if (oType != null && oType.IsValueType &&
        oType.IsGenericType && oType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
    {
        return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(oType);
    }
    else
    {
        return oType;
    }
}

private void GenerateTableColumns(DataTable dt, Type type, Stack<string> prefix, List<string> alreadyVisitedNodes, int depth)
{
    if (depth < 0)
        return;

    var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string) || !prop.PropertyType.IsClass)
        {
            if (prefix.Any())
            {
                var colName = $"{string.Join(".", prefix.Reverse())}.{prop.Name}";
                if (!dt.Columns.Contains(colName))
                    dt.Columns.Add(colName, BaseType(prop.PropertyType));
            }
            else
            {
                if (!dt.Columns.Contains(prop.Name))
                    dt.Columns.Add($"{prop.Name}", BaseType(prop.PropertyType));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (prefix.Contains(prop.Name) || alreadyVisitedNodes.Contains(prop.Name))
                continue;

            prefix.Push(prop.Name);
            alreadyVisitedNodes.Add(prop.Name);
            var currentDepth = depth - 1;
            GenerateTableColumns(dt, prop.PropertyType, prefix, alreadyVisitedNodes, currentDepth);
            prefix.Pop();
        }
    }
}

private void GenerateTableRows<T>(DataTable dt, User record)
{
    DataColumnCollection columns = dt.Columns;
    var values = new object[columns.Count];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataColumn column in columns)
    {
        values[i] = GetColumnValue(record, new Stack<string>(column.ColumnName.Split('.').Reverse()));
        i++;
    }
    try
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(values);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
}

  private object GetColumnValue<T>(T record, Stack<string> splittedColumnNameReversed)
 {
     if (record is string || record == null || record.GetType().IsPrimitive || record.GetType().IsValueType) return record;
     if (splittedColumnNameReversed.Count > 0)
     {
         var propertyName = splittedColumnNameReversed.Pop();
         PropertyInfo property = record.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
         if (property != null)
         {
             object value = null;
             try
             {
                 value = property.GetValue(record);
             }
             catch (System.Exception e)
             {
                 return null;
             }
             if (splittedColumnNameReversed.Count() == 0)
             {
                 return value;
             }
             else
             {
                 return GetColumnValue(value, splittedColumnNameReversed);
             }
         }
         else
         {
             return null;
         }
     }
     return record;
 }

This is working for small set of data. however when no of rows are reaching to more than 100... funtion never completes.
is there any better way to achieve it.
this is how columns  should look like.


